# Issue in extracting value associated with xml tag using python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have a `python` code where I am parsing an `xml` file and extracting all the `tags` from it. Now I want to extract a specific value related to a `tag` but finding some issues in doing so. A sample of my `xml` file looks like this:

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s65"><Data ss:Type="String">Variable Name</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s65"><Data ss:Type="String">Variable Label</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s79"><Data ss:Type="String">Minimum&#10;Value</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s79"><Data ss:Type="String">Maximum&#10;Value</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s80"><Data ss:Type="String">Mean&#10;Value</Data></Cell>

   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="15">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"><Data ss:Type="String">Marks</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"><Data ss:Type="String">Marks of Students</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="Number">96</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s83"><Data ss:Type="Number">65.71</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
```

Now the above is just a part of the whole xml file that I want to extract. I wrote this code to print all the tags in the xml file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
xmlTree = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('sample_xml.xml').getroot()

elemList = []

for elem in xmlTree.iter():
  elemList.append(elem.tag) # indent this by tab, not two spaces as I did here

# Just printing out the result

for element in elemList:
    print(element)
```

Now when I execute this code all I see is a repeating bunch of following sample output:

```
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Interior
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}NumberFormat
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Protection
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Worksheet
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Table
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Column
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Column
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Column
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Column
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Column
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Row
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Cell
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Data
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Row
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Cell
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Data
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Row
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Cell
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Data
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Row
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Cell
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Data
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Row
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Cell
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Data
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Row
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Cell
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Data
```

I don't know which Cell,Data, Row to target to extract the values I need(Marks,Marks of Students,Minimum,Maximum) as shown in sample xml format in the beginning. How can I do that?

**UPDATE:** Based on suggestions I am able to extract the text associated with the codes using following code:

```
for elem in xmlTree.iter():
    if elem.text != None:
        print(elem.text)
```

Now the issue is that in my xml file there are bunch of different texts but I want to extract the 4 texts that come right after these 4 tag texts - `Marks`,`Marks of Students`,`Minimum Marks`,`Maximum Marks`. I am trying to use `next()` if iterator to move to next tag when my current tag matches with `Marks` and keep on  matching next 3 tags in that order but it is not producing the desired result. Here is what I have written:

```
for elem in xmlTree.iter():
    if elem.text == 'Marks':
        if next(xmlTree.iter()) == 'Marks of Students':
            if next(xmlTree.iter()) == 'Minimum Value':
                if next(xmlTree.iter()) == 'Maximum Value':
                    print(next(elem.text))
                    print(next(elem.text))
                    print(next(elem.text))
                    print(next(elem.text))
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using what your XML with modification to make it well-formed. Please post *minimal but complete* sample XML, and corresponding output that demonstrate the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem with your XML file you have specified here. But i suspect your xml file might be in this format.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<Interior/>
<NumberFormat/>
<Protection/>
<Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="6" ss:ExpandedRowCount="2685" x:FullColumns="1"
x:FullRows="1">
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="26.25"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="117" ss:Span="3"/>
<Column ss:Index="6" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="29.25"/>
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="60">
<Cell ss:StyleID="s22"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s23"><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s23"><Data ss:Type="String">UserName</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s23"><Data ss:Type="String">Address</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s23"><Data ss:Type="String">Telephone Number</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s22"/>
</Row>
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="30">
<Cell ss:StyleID="s22"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="String">John Smith</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="String">JSmith</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="String">ABC</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="String">(999) 999-9999</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s22"/>
</Row>
</Table>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

If this is same then you can use the below code.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

with open('sample.xml') as xml_file:
    tree = etree.iterparse(xml_file)
    for item in tree:
        if item[1].text != None:
            print item[1].text
```

I have used the below reference for my understanding and copied the code.
[Reading Excel xml to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214511/reading-excel-xml-to-dictionary)

Comment: When I do `for elem in xmlTree.iter(): if elem[1].text != None:print(elem[1].text)` I get `IndexError: child index out of range`

Comment: I was able to resolve the above error but I am having one more issue. in my xml file there are bunch of different tag texts. Now what i want to do is check if tag text is `Marks` then check next 3 tages to see if they are `Marks of students,Minimum Marks,Maximum Marks` or not. If they are then extract the next 4 tag values otherwise continue. How can I do that?

Comment: I have updated my post above to reflect the current issue